# Is it possible to replicate bigger HDD onto smaller SSD, with Mac OS X El Capitan on the source HDD

Tags: ssd, osx-el-capitan, replicate

Is it possible to replicate bigger HDD onto smaller SSD, with Mac OS X El Capitan on the source HDD? I have a 240GB hard disk on my Macbook 7.1 running EL Capitan, I want to buy SSD of 120-128GB and use that one. On my hard disk I have around 100GB of data, and I want to replicate onto the new SSD that I will buy. Is this possible to do, or will I need to reinstall everything on the new SSD when I install it in, replacing the old hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Sharon Profis](http://www.cnet.com/profiles/sharonprofis/) on [this](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/upgrade-your-macbook-install-ssd-hard-drive/) CNET article, Mac has a clone feature built into disk utility. You may however encounter issues should your file storage exceed the capacity of your ssd. In which case I recommend you clear up space and move excess files to an external drive for later.

> Step 1: Prep the SSD
>
> Start by connecting the SSD to your computer with a dock or cable.
>   Once it's connected, launch Disk Utility (searchable through
>   Spotlight), and select your drive from the left sidebar. Then, head to
>   the Erase tab, and click Erase. No need to change any settings, unless
>   you'd like to give it a new name. This will format the drive and prep
>   it for the next step.
>
> Launch SuperDuper, and set it to clone your Mac's hard drive to the
>   SSD. If you gave it a new name in Disk Utility, it'll show up as such.
>   Then choose Backup All Files, and click Copy Now.
>
> This could take anywhere from 30 minutes to 3 hours depending on how
>   much you have stored on your hard drive. When the process is complete,
>   eject the SSD and shut down your computer.
>
> Step 2: Remove the hard drive
>
> In case you missed it in the previous step, shut down your computer.
>
> Begin by removing your MacBook's back cover. There are 10 screws in
>   total, including three longer ones. Put them in a small container as
>   you remove them.
>
> When the cover comes off, touch a metal part to release the static
>   electricity. At this point, you might want to clean the inside of your
>   Mac. I found that after years without cleaning, mine was full of dust.
>   Use a soft brush or gentle bursts of compressed air to release the
>   dust and grime.
>
> To remove the hard drive, use the regular screwdriver to unscrew the
>   two black screws belonging to the bracket securing the hard drive.
>   Remove the bracket and set it aside.
>
> Gently lift the hard drive. You'll see that a ribbon is attached to
>   one end. Carefully wiggle the connector -- not the ribbon itself -- to
>   disconnect it.
>
> Remove the four torx screws attached to the hard drive and set aside.
>   At this point, you can store your hard drive away or convert it to an
>   external hard drive. You're done with it.
>
> Step 3: Install the SSD
>
> Grab the SSD and screw in the four torx screws you removed from the
>   hard drive. Then, carefully attach the ribbon to the SSD, and insert
>   the drive in the same configuration as the previous drive.
>
> Re-attach the bracket. And finally, replace the back cover using the
>   10 screws.
>
> If you made it this far without fumbling, congratulations! That was
>   probably easier than you were expecting.
>
> Now turn on your computer. It may take a couple of extra seconds as it
>   gets acquainted with the new drive, but generally speaking, starting
>   up your computer will be much faster than the past. You'll also notice
>   that programs launch faster, saving files takes less time, and it
>   feels less sluggish overall.

Comment: Link only answers are not recommended here, at least put most of the instructions in your answer.

Comment: @Moab isn't that inefficient? Why copy an entire instruction set when its already stored off site? Seems inefficient and rather plagerisy

Comment: @Moab Also the guidelines specify putting the authors name if you're going to quote them, which I feel I didn't need to as I just gave a link.

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable, period. A link to the information copied from another source is also serves as posting the author.

Comment: We are not here for efficiency but documentation, links rot in time so your answer in the original form would become null and void. This is not a forum but leans more toward a wiki site.

Comment: @Moab That's fair. But on a CNET link?

Comment: @Moab Also if a link fails and no author is mentioned what happens to that data?

Comment: @Moab Also the guidelines say not to quote an entire page of text like you just did. It says, Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it. Which I feel I did. I linked to it and then paraphrased. My only infraction I believe is that I did not cite the author of the document.